# MAUI How to align Label and Picker?

Tags: maui

I want to have a label and a border with a picker inside and texts of both aligned. I have tried many things, but I cannot get this to work under MAUI on Android emulators or physical devices.
I can get a nearly perfect solution on Windows Machine, but this wont work on some Android emulators and devices.
I assume it is a MAUI bug, but is there a workaround?
I am using MAUI .NET6

Reproduction:

- Take standard MAUI app template
- Add PickerBorderStyle and FlexOptionsStyle

```xml
<Style x:Key="PickerBorderStyle" TargetType="Border">
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="3,0,7,0"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="3,0,3,0"/>
    <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Green"/>
</Style>
```

Change Picker default style to

```xml
<Style TargetType="Picker">
    <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Gray900}, Dark={StaticResource White}}" />
    <Setter Property="TitleColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Gray900}, Dark={StaticResource Gray200}}" />
    <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Yellow" />
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="OpenSansRegular"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalTextAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalTextAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2,0,0,0"/>
    <Setter Property="VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups">
        <VisualStateGroupList>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                    <VisualState.Setters>
                        <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Gray300}, Dark={StaticResource Gray600}}" />
                        <Setter Property="TitleColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Gray300}, Dark={StaticResource Gray600}}" />
                    </VisualState.Setters>
                </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateGroupList>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Add this above the CounterBtn

```xml
<HorizontalStackLayout Margin="2,1" Padding="0" HeightRequest="40">
    <Label x:Name="lbBoardEdgeStyle" Text="Chimps"  VerticalOptions="Center" Margin="3,0"/>
    <Border Style="{StaticResource PickerBorderStyle}">
        <Picker x:Name="cbBoardEdgeStyle" 
                VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions ="Center"  WidthRequest="100">
            <Picker.ItemsSource>
                <x:Array Type="{x:Type x:String}">
                    <x:String>Capuchin Monkey</x:String>
                    <x:String>Blue Monkey</x:String>
                    <x:String>Japanese Macaque</x:String>
                </x:Array>
            </Picker.ItemsSource>
        </Picker>
    </Border>
</HorizontalStackLayout>
```

Run it and select "Blue Monkey". Looks fine and nearly aligned on

Windows Machine:

[image]

and on some Android emulators:

[image]

but quite unaligned on some Android emulators or physical devices:

[image]

[image]

Edit: FreakyAli's proposal with the VerticleTextAlignment="End" makes things worse:
[image]

Comment: I don't understand what the expected result is. Can you clarify? Also, you should try to use .NET 8.0.

Comment: I want to have the text of the Label and Picker aligned. The vertical distance between the word "Chimps" and the upper red line should be the same as the vertical distance between "Blue Monkey" and teh red line.... Those red rectangles I've painted into the pictures are there only for their upper line - to indicate a baseline for the texts.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand this is what you need to change the following:

```
<Label x:Name="lbBoardEdgeStyle" Text="Chimps"  VerticleTextAlignment="End" Margin="3,0"/> 
<Border Style="{StaticResource PickerBorderStyle}">
    <Picker x:Name="cbBoardEdgeStyle" 
            VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions ="Center"  WidthRequest="100">
        <Picker.ItemsSource>
            <x:Array Type="{x:Type x:String}">
                <x:String>Capuchin Monkey</x:String>
                <x:String>Blue Monkey</x:String>
                <x:String>Japanese Macaque</x:String>
            </x:Array>
        </Picker.ItemsSource>
    </Picker>
</Border>
```

Also note that the margin you have on your label will affect your View's aligment

Comment: Do I see it right, the only thing you changed i VerticalTextAlignment of the Label to "End"?

Comment: Yes it should do what you need

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't, it makes things worse. I've added a screenshot to the question.

Comment: Oh now i get it, i misunderstood your question my bad now i get it, Can you try VerticleAlignment as Center